# Find usage in Visual C++ with Visual Assist

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010, visual-assist

I am using VS 2010, does Visual C++ with Visual Assist provide refactor functions on finding usage of variables? I right click the variable and the find usage function is always grey out.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me right clicking on a variable and selecting Refactor (VA) - Find References.

Answer (score 1):

Find All References in the context menu is the IDE version of the command.

To use Find References from Visual Assist, try one of:

1. open the "Refactoring (VA)" sub-menu of the context menu
2. use the default shortcut Shift+Alt+F
3. open the Quick Refactoring Menu with Shift+Alt+Q ("refactoring" is used loosely in this instance.)